# Mobile Display of website's carousel makes <div> keep original height but only on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have been learning Html and css the past three weeks. I am currently building my own portfolio without any external tools, and I encountered a problem that seems to make no sense whatsoever even after googling for similar responses.

The image found in the code snipper is part of a carousel. I have tested the website both in safari and chrome using both  iphone 6 and iphone 11 but there still seems to be a problem. This however does not happen when inspecting element on the browser and setting it the the phone view as seen here:

[image: Image Observed in mobile view in firefox inspector]

Before "object-fit:contain" was added, the ".carouselContainer" div itself was already getting extended height. Without "object-fit:contain" it stretches the image vertically (only in actual mobile), however with the div ".carouselContainer" keeps the old height of the image, without stretching the actual image, but leaving a big empty gap as observed here:

[image: Image Observed in safari in iphone 6]

The website is online and found [here](https://pedro-rainha.com). I am grateful and thank you in advance for your help!

```css
.carousel-container
{
    display: inline-block;

    width:100%;
    min-height: 0%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
}

.carousel-container img
{
    min-width:100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.carousel-slide
{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
  <input type="image" src="./images/LeftArrow.png" id="prevBtn"></input>
  <input type="image" src="./images/RightArrow.png" id="nextBtn"></input>
  <div class="carousel-slide">
    <img src="https://img.wallpapersafari.com/desktop/1920/1080/74/99/M67dUT.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `min-width` to `width` inside the `carousel-container img` css.

Also, you might not need other css in here

```
.carousel-container img
{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this does not work. This is how it was previously, and it stretches the image vertically. So I decided to add object-fit:contain, but that keeps the same height of the stretching, but the image no longer stretches, it only keeps a big blank as observed in the second picture!